# Google Chrome 6.0.472.59 Update Breaks JavaScript Bookmarks

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, bookmarks, javascript

I just updated to the latest version of Google Chrome (6.0.472.59) and my bookmarks that are just JavaScript will not work anymore. The JavaScript wont even run when I paste it into the address bar.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: What OS? I've just checked mine on Windows-XP and it seems fine.

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome has updated since then and the issue has been resolved.